# Spider Bite : Swelling every 12 months - why?

Tags: coloration-discoloration, swelling, venom, shape-form-pattern, spider-bites

My father was bitten by a spider on the left side of his forehead in 1989 while visiting America.  The type of spider was never identified but the swelling was severe (almost baseball sized).   He recovered with no ill effects.

However each summer, around the anniversary of the bite, in extremely hot weather, the bite location will swell and become red/inflamed.

He has never sought medical care for the swelling but it has remained a mystery/puzzle.

In the 90's he was resigned to never knowing why but I thought I would pose the question to SE to finally shed some light on the issue.

The swelling has not returned since approximately 2002-3 and appears that whatever caused it has dissipated but I have wondered for a long time what would cause a decade long cycle of swelling?

Comment: Looks dangerous. Why don't he see a doctor?

Comment: I think he medical care he received in the USA was sufficient and UK General Practicioners do not deal with venomous insect / animal bites as we have none in the UK (save for the Adder).  He never worried about the swelling - the situation is now more for curiosity.

Comment: Reducing his life expectancy?  Why?  Surely venom has a shelf-life within which to impact living organisms?

Comment: I doubt it was a spider bite because [spiders don't bite](http://arthropodecology.com/2012/02/15/spiders-do-not-bite/). Consider a second opinion without presupposing it was a spider bite.

Comment: @CareyGregory- that is not what the article says.  It says they rarely bite.  This wound was a spider bite since the victim was in actual fact bitten by a spider.  Plus it's clear you didn't even read the question thoroughly.  Also the article you posted has a map showing biting, venomous spiders which put the bubble squarely over where my father was bit.

Comment: I read the question thoroughly. And I simply used the title of the article for my link so there's no need to get upset about it. All you've said is you're sure it was a spider bite and I pointed out it might not be.